# What can be done about "The command is too long to execute" error in MATLAB?

Tags: python, matlab

I am calling a Python program from MATLAB and passing an array to the program. I am writing the following lines in MATLAB workspace:

```
% Let us assume some random array

num1 = ones(1,100);   

% I am forced to pass parameters as string due to the MATLAB-Python interaction.

num2 = num2str(num1);    

% The function is saved in a Python program called squared.py

z=python('squared.py',num2);
```

The program works fine when the size of `num1` is small (e.g. 100). However, when it is large, e.g., 500000, MATLAB shows the following error:

```
??? Error using ==> dos
The command is too long to execute.

Error in ==> python at 68
[status, result] = dos(pythonCmd);
```

Does anyone know how to fix this error?

Comment: I think this might be a DOS issue. Are you running this from commandline or are you using the MATLAB GUI?

Comment: not really an answer, but can't you write the huge array to file from matlab and then let the python program read it and do its magic?

Answer (score 8):

On Windows, the command passed to the `dos` function is limited to 32768 characters. This limitation comes from the Windows limitation on the `lpCommandLine` parameter to [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

I think Fredrik's idea of writing the data to a file and reading it from Python is your best alternative.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all of your commands. I really appreciate your help. I have two questions.                                                  1. How can I send a file to Python?  As far as I have seen, the python command in Matlab only accepts a string, e.g, in the following command:

z=python('squared.py',num2);
 
If num2 is anything apart from a string, Matlab shows an error. I want to know if a bin file will also work.

Comment: 2.  I am currently trying to convert my array to a bin file. I am using the following command:

fid = fopen('nazmul.bin','wb');     // opening a bin file
fwrite(fid,array1);                    // array1 is the array that I want to send to Python

However, it's not working properly. When I read the 'nazmul.bin' file, I find the output array to be completely blank.               
fid = fopen('nazmul.bin','wb');
A=fread(fid);

I find A to be an empty array. Ideally, I would like A to be equal to array1. I am new to this type of Matlab-Python conversion work. Your help will be very appreciated.

Comment: When you read the file you need to use 'rb' mode (read binary). You're opening it 'wb' (write binary) which empties the file out.

Comment: Thanks a lot SCFrench. The reading issue got resolved. Right now, I am facing problem in passing the bin file to Python and reading it in the program. Therefore, I will edit my original question and put my recent inquiry there. It will be great if any of you can resolve the updated inquiry. Nazmul

Comment: If it's a different problem, I'd recommend creating a new question instead of editing this one.